# Where do I use AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Per the docs in my beanstalk folder, I have `~/myapp/.ebextensions/appname.conf`:

```
OptionSettings:
  AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration:
    InstanceType: t2.medium
```

I also tried it in `env.yaml`:

```
AWSConfigurationTemplateVersion: 1.1.0.0
OptionSettings:
  AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration:
    InstanceType: t2.medium
```

But beanstalk utterly refuses to provision anything but a micro. What am I doing wrong? Where do I put this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `eb config save --cfg AllTheStuffISetupInTheUI` writes out all the stuff I setup in the UI and pretty much writes the env file for me.

To that end, all three options need to be present for this to work:

```
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    IamInstanceProfile: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
    InstanceType: t2.medium
    EC2KeyName: mysecretkeys
```